# Connect LCD to TVBOX to set top box to play HDTV

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi, video-conversion

Hi I have a really old LCD monitor that supports only VGA or DVI-D. I want to use it to play HDTV so I bought a set top box, which supports outputs 1. Composite 2. Component YPbPr 3. HDMI.

Because there is no direct ports between the set top box and my LCD monitor, so I dig out my old TV box which supports inputs 1. RF 2. Composite 3. Component YCbCr 4. PC VGA and outputs VGA.

Currently I am using the composite to connects the set top box to my TV box, but I find the screen quality is not really good, I want to ask which of the following is the best combination to get better screen quality and the cheapest for my devices? Thank you!

1. Buy a HDMI to DVI-D cable, connects set top box directly to monitor
2. Buy a HDMI to VGA convertor, connects set top box directly to monitor
3. Buy a YPbPr to YCbCr cable/convertor?, connects set top box to TV box then to monitor
4. Buy a HDMI to YCbCr cable/convertor?, connects set top box to TV box then to monitor

Comment: As far as I can tell, HDMI to DVI-D seems to make the most sense, as only an adapter is required and can be bought from sites like Monoprice for less than US$5. The other options all require a converter. I didn't put this as an answer because I'm not entirely sure - other users may have better explanations.

Comment: Thank you. $5 sounds good to give it a try. You could have answered seeing that the only answer is the same as yours ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDMI->DVI-D is the best choice for maximum allowed resolution and they're cheap ($5-15 at your local Target/WalMart) and most LCD's handle native digital resolutions better than composite/component scaling anyways.

Comment: Thank you. I am just not sure if all HDMI can be adapted to DVI-D without a converter. But I am sure I can learn a lesson for $5.

Comment: HDMI allows for HDCP (think BluRay), DVI-D does not. This does not mean you can't watch BluRay through DVI-D connection, it just means the HDCP link is not there (and better off for it IMHO) .. As long as you're using the HDMI->DVI as way to connect to your LCD, you'll be alright :)